# Intuition behind the correlation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm following this [tutorial online from kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/pmarcelino/comprehensive-data-exploration-with-python) and I can't get my head round why `.T` is changing the shape of the matrix. Here is the part I am stuck at:

```
#saleprice correlation matrix
k = 10 #number of variables for heatmap
cols = corrmat.nlargest(k, 'SalePrice')['SalePrice'].index
cm = np.corrcoef(df_train[cols].values.T)
sns.set(font_scale=1.25)
hm = sns.heatmap(cm, cbar=True, annot=True, square=True, fmt='.2f', annot_kws={'size': 10}, yticklabels=cols.values, xticklabels=cols.values)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I'm basically trouble shooting the code and tried this:

```
 cm = np.corrcoef(df_train[cols].values)
 cm.shape
```

returns a matrix with shape `1460x1460`. But when I input:

```
 cm = np.corrcoef(df_train[cols].values.T)
 cm.shape
```

it returns a matrix with shape `10x10`. Does anyone know why it does this? I can't figure out.

Comment: I wonder what .T does?

Comment: It means to transpose the matrix (notation is from Numpy documentation).

Comment: Then maybe np.corrcoef depends on the transpose state of the input matrix. What does np.corrcoef do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correlation gives you a *normalized* representation of the covariance matrix between all the "columns" of the dataframe. For instance, in the case of having only two variables, you'd end up with a matrix of the shape:

```
Rx =  [[   1,    r_xy],
       [r_yx,       1]]
```

This is quite an expensive computation, since it involves taking the dot product of each column with the rest, resulting in a correlation coefficient for each combination.

So in matrix notation, since you want to end up with a `10x10` matrix, you want to have the shapes correctly aligned. In this case you want `(10,1460)x(1460,10)` so you get a `10,10` matrix. Hence you need to transpose the 2D-array so that it has shape `(10,1460)` when you feed it to `np.corrcoef`.

Though you might find it a little easier by playing around with it yourself and seeing how the actual [Pearson correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) is computed:

```
X = np.random.randint(0,10,(500,2))
print(np.corrcoef(X.T))

array([[1.        , 0.04400245],
       [0.04400245, 1.        ]])
```

Which is doing the same as:

```
mean_X = X.mean(axis=0)
std_X = X.std(axis=0)
n, _ = X.shape

print((X.T-mean_X[:,None]).dot(X-mean_X)/(n*std_X**2))

array([[1.        , 0.04416552],
       [0.04383998, 1.        ]])
```

Note that as mentioned, this is giving as result a *normalized* [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of *X* with itself, so for each `(1,1460)x(1460,1)` product your getting a single number. So `X` here, just as in your example, has to be transposed so the dimensions are correctly aligned.

Comment: Brilliant, just what I was looking for. When you say 'normalised' what do you mean? I am interpreting it as a nominal value to represent two variables, is that correct?

Comment: Normalized in the sense that it is subtracted by the mean and the standard deviations are divided @apang

Answer (score 1):

From numpy [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) of corrcoef:

```
x : array_like
A 1-D or 2-D array containing multiple variables and observations. 
Each row of x represents a variable, and 
each column a single observation of all those variables. Also see rowvar below.
```

Note that each **row** represents a variable, in the first case you have 1460 rows and 10 columns and in the second one you have 10 rows with 1460 columns.

So when you transpose your NumPy array your basically changing from 1460 variables with 10 values for each one to 10 variables with 1460 values for each one.

If you are dealing with pandas you could just use the built-in [.corr()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) method that computes the correlation between **columns**.